# PHP Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in D:\Hosting\110000\html\xxxx\wp-admin\includes\network.php on line 353

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I tried to install multisite in my site when click Network Setup in tools:

I'm getting: 
    PHP Warning:  strpos(): Empty needle in D:\Hosting\110000\html\xxxx\wp-admin\includes\network.php on line 353

```
/**
 * Prints step 2 for Network installation process.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @global wpdb $wpdb WordPress database abstraction object.
 *
 * @param WP_Error $errors
 */
function network_step2( $errors = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $hostname          = get_clean_basedomain();
    $slashed_home      = trailingslashit( get_option( 'home' ) );
    $base              = parse_url( $slashed_home, PHP_URL_PATH );
    $document_root_fix = str_replace( '\\', '/', realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ) );
    $abspath_fix       = str_replace( '\\', '/', ABSPATH );
    $home_path         = 0 === strpos( $abspath_fix, $document_root_fix ) ? $document_root_fix . $base : get_home_path();
    $wp_siteurl_subdir = preg_replace( '#^' . preg_quote( $home_path, '#' ) . '#', '', $abspath_fix );
    $rewrite_base      = ! empty( $wp_siteurl_subdir ) ? ltrim( trailingslashit( $wp_siteurl_subdir ), '/' ) : '';


    $location_of_wp_config = $abspath_fix;
    if ( ! file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' ) && file_exists( dirname( ABSPATH ) . '/wp-config.php' ) ) {
        $location_of_wp_config = dirname( $abspath_fix );
    }
    $location_of_wp_config = trailingslashit( $location_of_wp_config );
```

line 353:

```
$home_path         = 0 === strpos( $abspath_fix, $document_root_fix ) ? $document_root_fix . $base : get_home_path();
```

Wordpress files are not in the root folder, but in a subdirectory and the domain i'm using is pointed to that subdirectory.

How can add a wordpress multisite network?

Any idea how to solve this.

Please help.

[Screenshot of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4QSk.png)

Comment: How are you installing WordPress? I see you are on windows. [real_path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) does work a bit different on Windows. The problem is probably somewhere in your setup.

Comment: I am using shared hosting, and the files are in the subdirectory, mapped to the domain spinebiz.net

Comment: @janw My server configuration is as follows: PHP Version 5.4.16, mysqlnd 5.0.10 and the wordpress version is 4.9.5 latest. Is there anything related to the php version?

Comment: While you _can_ run WP on Windows, and you _can_ run WP on PHP 5.4, I'd **strongly** suggest running on PHP 7.1+ (5.4 is past end-of-life), and life would be much simpler running it on a Linux server....

Comment: Thank you @cale_b, I have tested the same wp files and database in the localhost where the php version is 7.1 and it is working fine. I'll check again with an older version of the php whether php version is the problem.

Comment: I figured this was local development on a Windows. Like @cale_b siad. linux is far better supported. Also you missed the webserver (apache?) Which is far more important then mysql.

Comment: @janw this is not local development but in Godaddy hosting. I have tested the multisite installation in an older version of the php and it is working fine. Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small chain to follow:

the *needle* is `$document_root_fix`.
Which is created in part with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

I'm guessing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not set or empty.
If this is the case that's probably apache's fault. How are you installing the multisite? Via the website or are you using some tool like [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/)?

A dirty solution is to hardcode this fix.

```
$home_path = get_home_path();
```

***!!!Be sure to change it back after installing!!!***

Comment: The issue was fixed using this solution. Thanks @janw

Comment: Did you change it back?

Comment: yes, after the network installation I have changed it back.